# How to manage sms and reply from webapp through twilio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, twilio, twilio-php

I'm creating a messaging web application with laravel 5.1 and twilio and i'm using [laravel-twilio](https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio) package.

**Settings and configuration already done in twilio dashboard**

1. In Programmable SMS section i'hv created a messaging service with copilot which includes a single phone number ((xxx) xxx-xxx).
2. Given a Inbound request url.

**My laravel application code**

I have simple user to user messaging where both user are online where nothing to do with twilio. But suppose one of the user is offline and another one is online and the online user send a chat message to offline user then i have to notify the the offline user through an sms to this user's phone number via twilo.

```
    public static function notifyOfflineUser($user,$reply_text){
            $message = "Mysite: ".$user->user_from->firstname.", '".strip_tags($reply_text)."' Reply via mysite ".url('general-message')." or SMS";
            if($user->profile->mobile) {
                try {
                    \Twilio::message($user->profile->mobile, $message);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

It's sending a sms to the user from the twilio phone number.

Where the user can reply to this message form his/her phone to this number.
And if the reply succeded i have to add the message to the online user's message board.

```
//Inbound request url routed to this url with From number, body and other data.

    public function smsReply(Request $request){

        $user_id_to = Profile::where('mobile', $request->get('From'))->first(['user_id'])->user_id;
        $body = $request->get('Body');

        $user_id_from = Message::where('user_id_to', $user_id_to)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->user_id_from;

        //dd($request->all());
        $message = new Message();
        $message->user_id_from                  = $user_id_to;
        $message->user_id_to                    = $user_id_from;
        $message->message                       = $body;
        $message->save();
        return response()->json(true);
    }
```

Now if multiple online user send chat message to this offline user, offline user will get miltiple sms from the same twilio number and those all sms are coming in a same stack, that mean it's not coming in different sms if he/she reply to the sms it will send to the same number, and all online user will get same message added in their message board.

Now here is my question..

Is there anything else need form twilio like multiple number, short codes, tollfree or i have to do the trick with my laravel code so i can send each sms to the offline user's phone as a different sms so i can distinguish them from inbound request url ? Feel free to ask me if more information needed.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to be able to deal with multiple conversations like that, you're going to need multiple numbers. That way a number can represent the relationship between two users and you can tell what the user is responding to.

I recommend you check out this [tutorial on building SMS conversations using multiple numbers with Laravel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/php/laravel) for more information.

Comment: How many number i need? At the time of being offline 100 of user can send chat message to him/her so do i need 100 numbers or more?

Comment: You need as many numbers as the maximum number of relationships between users. Check out this article for the details: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio

Comment: You don't need either of those. You just need enough numbers to cover the maximum number of conversations a user can have. Note, once a conversation is done with you can then reuse a number or release it.